# gs - How to take A1's value, search for it in col 1 of a list on another sheet, get the row, then fill A2 with the value from col 2 of that row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Google Sheets

I have 2 Sheets: 
[Signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAAtP.png) & 
[Employee List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES0V7.png)

Employees can signup for a session by entering or selecting their name from the Drop Down in column D on the Signup Sheet. Entries are validated and rejected if failed.

When they do so, based on the Name entered, I need to be able to take the Employee Email and Employee Phone from the Employee List Sheet's columns B & C and put their values into the Signup Sheet's columns E & F, respectively.

For now I am doing everything with a script onEdit and am fairly certain I can pull it off.

However, is there a way to do it with a formula in the Contact Email and Contact Phone column's cells of the Signup Sheet?

I would like to keep things as simple and clean as possible and the onEdit code seems to lag quite a bit as I add code to it. (onEdit only runs if the specified range on the signup sheet is edited)

Is there a relatively simple way to do this that I do not know of?

Let me know if you need clarification and I can provide the code I have in my scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the vlookup function - which breaks down like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,'EmployeeList'!A:C,2,false)
```

D2 is the employees name on the first sheet in the dropdown, i made up a sheet name for the second one, but the second parameter references hte other sheet, and tells it which columns to search, the first column must be the one with the matching search term.

The 2 stands for which column index you want, so for contact email you want the second column, and for contact phone you will only slightly adjust the formula to be:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,'EmployeeList'!A:C,3,false)
```

if you want to apply it to the whole column, you can do two things - force it to only run if there is a value by wrapping it in an 'istext' formula, and then wrapping the whole thing in an array formula:

```
=arrayformula(If(istext(D2:D),VLOOKUP(D2:D,'EmployeeList'!A2:C,2,false),))
```

Comment: I knew my thinking was taking me the long way round.  Thanks so much Aurielle, it works perfect!